# Como sumar valores cada vez cuando ingreso datos a la base de datos SQL con C# y win forms

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

Cómo agregar valores cada vez que inserto a la base de datos y recuerde los valores Total de insertos anteriores. Quiero sumar campo  Name en campo Total. Y cuado reinicio la aplicacion quiero que recuerde el ultimo Total.

Esto es mi codigo de class clans..

public class clans

```
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Craft { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }   
    public decimal Total {get; set; }
```

Este codigo es para insertar en SQL Table obb:

```
        cl.Name = txtInsertName.Text;
        cl.Craft = txtInsertCraft.Text;
        cl.Month = Convert.ToInt32(txtInsertMounth.Text);
        cl.Year = Convert.ToInt32(txtInsertYear.Text);
        cl.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtInsertPrice.Text);

      cl.Total += cl.Price;//en esta manera hago suma pero cuando reinicio la aplicacion mo me recuerda el ultimo Total

        SqlCommand cmd;

            string query = "insert into obb(Name,Craft,Month,Year,Price,Total) values(@p1,@p2,@p3,@p5,@p6,@p7)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, db);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cl.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", cl.Craft);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", cl.Month);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", cl.Year);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", cl.Price);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", cl.Total);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Los codigos para datagridview
        string query1 = @" SELECT * FROM obb order by Name ASC, Year ASC";
        clansBindingSource1.DataSource = db.Query<clans>(query1, commandType: CommandType.Text);
```

Comment: Si solo guardaras el valor de un campo, puedes  crear una variable de configuración en el Visual Studio, y al cerrar el formulario guardar la información ahí y al cargar el formulario en el load buscar el dato, o guardar ese dato en un archivo XML, o almacenar el dato directamente en la base de datos., Si te interesa esa idea te muestro un ejemplo.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No entiendo que queres hacer. Podrias aclarar mucho mas cual es la idea que estas persiguiendo con esto?

Answer (score 1):

Quizás haya muchas formas de hacer esto que pide, pero aquí le muestro una forma si desea implementarla, independientemente del código que tiene realizado, solo le mostraré como guardar el valor y recuperarlo al cargar la aplicación nuevamente, es algo como esto:

1- Primero en su `Visual Studio` de Click en el menú en `Proyecto (Project)` y luego diríjase abajo a `Propiedades del Proyecto (Properties)`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2- Segundo diríjase al apartado `Configuración (Settings)` y cree su variable, `Nombre`, `TipoDato` etc.:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3- Para guardar su `Total` en esta variable haga lo siguiente en el evento del Formulario `FormClosed` o `FormClosing` el que desee:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Total_Nombres = cl.Total;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

4- Para recuperar este valor al iniciar la aplicación debe hacer lo siguiente en el evento `Load` del formulario:

```
cl.Total = Properties.Settings.Default.Total_Nombres;
```

Esto sería todo, tal como dije hay mas formas de hacerlo, esta es la que de pronto se me ocurre, espero le sirva de ayuda.

Comment: La idea con almacenar en la base de datos me gustaria que me muestras, porfavor

Comment: Esto no es una buena idea. Recuperar el valor de una variable que deberia ser calculada desde una properties no es algo que deberia hacerse.

Comment: @gbianchi tal y como expresé en la respuesta dije que es una idea y que hay muchas mas formas de hacerlo.